# How can I capture specific network calls using python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, networking, automation, python-requests

I want to capture specific network call when a page is loaded or an action is performed on the page. Here's what I tried.

```
from browsermobproxy import Server
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
```

```
# Start BrowserMob Proxy
server = Server("C:\\Users\\RagavendraKumarM\\Downloads\\browsermob-proxy-2.1.4-bin\\browsermob-proxy-2.1.4\\bin\\browsermob-proxy")
server.start()
proxy = server.create_proxy()
```

```
# Set up Chrome WebDriver with proxy configuration
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxy.proxy}')
chrome_driver_path = ChromeDriverManager().install()
service = webdriver.chrome.service.Service(chrome_driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

# Create a new HAR with a consistent name
proxy.new_har("google")

# Navigate to the website
driver.get("https://www.google.com")

# Wait for some time after page load to allow network requests to be captured
# (You might need to adjust this based on the website's loading behavior)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'body')))

# Print the captured HAR
print(proxy.har)

# Stop BrowserMob Proxy
server.stop()

# Quit the WebDriver
driver.quit()
```

**OUTPUT**
{'log': {'version': '1.2', 'creator': {'name': 'BrowserMob Proxy', 'version': '2.1.4', 'comment': ''}, 'pages': [{'id': 'google', 'startedDateTime': '2024-01-02T22:06:56.982+05:30', 'title': 'google', 'pageTimings': {'comment': ''}, 'comment': ''}], 'entries': [], 'comment': ''}}